# Why does a property called DefaultStringValue always appear first in IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper, intellisense

If you define the following class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Something { get; set; }  
    public string AnotherThing { get; set; }  
    public string DefaultStringValue { get; set; }
}
```

then, when you list the properties with IntelliSense, `DefaultStringValue` appears first in the list, despite this not being in alphabetical order:

[image]

If you change the property name to *anything* else, normal service is resumed:

[image]

Anyone know why this is? I'm curious...

(Note: I'm also using Resharper Ultimate 2018.1.2)

Comment: Are you using Resharper?

Comment: Yes, I am. Probably should have mentioned that in the question. Resharper Ultimate 2018.1.2.

Comment: Note that it's never too late to [edit] your question to include information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is IntelliSense (and/or ReSharper) being, well, intelli-gent, and trying to help you re-use things you've used previously.  If you start again from nothing, you'll find that things are alphabetical:

[image]

I'm betting that at some point in the past, you've made use of the `DefaultStringValue` property, and not the others, so it's suggesting it first:

[image]

[image]

Having renamed it, if you enter the line `t.DefaultStringValu = "x";`, then delete it again, next time you enter `t.` and invoke IntelliSense, `DefaultStringValu` will now be top of the list:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doh. Yep, you're right of course. And I'm sure I've been unconsciously relying on this behaviour in the past, now I think of it.